# How to fix timer increasing countdown speed with each button press

Tags: python, tkinter

I already read a thread that helped my problem with turning the button[state] to 'normal' and 'disabled'.

I would really like to know and learn if there is a conditional/boolean way to do this.

How, or can you start a timer with a button and not have the timer speed up if a user clicks the start button again?

I tried several times to implement a conditional, checking if the button had been pressed, if the time was less than the original variable amount, etc.

But each time the timer would countdown faster and faster with each click. I feel like there is an issue on my part in understanding the fundamentals of how conditionals/booleans work.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

hold_time = 120
timer = False


def start_timer():
    global timer
    timer = True
    hold_timer_start()
    start_button['state'] = 'disabled'

def hold_timer_start():

    global hold_time
    global timer

    if timer == True:
        hold_time -= 1
        hold_timer_label['text'] = hold_time
        hold_timer_label.after(1000, hold_timer_start)
        if hold_time == 0:
            timer = False

def hold_timer_stop():
    global hold_time
    global timer

    hold_time = 120
    hold_timer_label['text'] = hold_time
    timer = False

    start_button['state'] = 'normal'


timer_frame = Frame(root, bg='gray25')  
timer_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

hold_timer_label = Label(timer_frame, text='Hold Time', bg='skyblue')
hold_timer_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew', columnspan=2, pady=2)

hold_timer_label = Label(timer_frame, text=hold_time, bg='white')  
hold_timer_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew', columnspan=2, pady=2)

empty_label = Label(timer_frame, bg='gray25')  
empty_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

start_button = Button(timer_frame, text='Start', bg='green', fg='black', command=start_timer)  
start_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

stop_button = Button(timer_frame, text='Stop', bg='red', fg='black',command=hold_timer_stop)  
stop_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

empty_label = Label(timer_frame, bg='gray25')  
empty_label.grid(row=2, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

I expect the timer to start counting down once the button is pressed but then do nothing if pressed again while the timer is counting down.

Unless the timer has hit zero or the stop button has been pressed.

Comment: seems that all is working ok. I can't press start again if once is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `timer` flag set. All you need to do is to check it.

```
def start_timer():
    global timer
    if not timer:
        timer = True
        hold_timer_start()
        #start_button['state'] = 'disabled'
```

Comment: Ok, so to understand correctly. Using the "not" conditional is like saying if timer = false then timer = true?  Because once I set the timer to true and check it again, the condition that it's false IS false and won't run again, correct?

Comment: Yes. It is equivalent to `if timer == False` if you want to be explicit about what you are checking.